# Swift 3: unrecognized selector sent to instance for gesture recognizer

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uitapgesturerecognizer

No matter what I do, I always get this error.

This is inside my `cellForItemAtIndexPath` function:

```
cell.postCell.profileImage.userView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "pressedUserImage:"))
```

and the action method:

```
func pressedUserImage(userView: UIImageView) {
    print(userView.superview) // error happens here.
```

Now of course, my userView is within a deep view hierarchy but it still has to work. For some reason it doesn't.  Even if I do `userImage.superview?.superview` and so forth, I still get the error. 
I tried using `#selector(pressedUserImage(_:)` instead, but no luck. Tried `Selector("pressedUserImage:")`. Nothing.

Where am I going wrong here?

Update, here's the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` function:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellID", for: indexPath) as! Posts
    cell.postCell.profileImage.userView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "pressedUserImage:"))
    cell.postCell.buttonView.sharePost.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pressedShareButton), for: .touchUpInside)

    return cell
}
```

`postCell` is basically a `UIView` that contains the image, name, text.

Here's the error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[project.Posts pressedUserImage]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7a9a65e0'

Comment: can you share the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` function?

Comment: Can you also show the exact exception message text

Comment: The parameter to a gesture recognizer handler is the gesture recognizer, no the touched view. Use .view on the sender to get the sending view.

Comment: Sorry about that, all there.

Comment: @vacawama, what would you mean? a UITapGestureRecognizer is a gesture recognizer, no?

Comment: See JoshuaKaden's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the problem is with your function signature. It needs to accept the gesture recognizer as a parameter, not the containing view.

Like:

```
func pressedUserImage(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) { ... }
```

Comment: And then you can get the view like this: `if let userView = sender.view as? UIImageView { // use userView }`

Comment: !!!!!! now I gotta go to Home Depot to buy dry wall cement. Thanks guys! It worked.

Answer (score 0):

As Joshua pointed out, your function signature was wrong. You need to set the type of the parameter correctly, and add an underscore to make the parameter un-named.

In addition to his changes, you should also flag the function as Objective-C if your class is not an Objective-C class:

```
@objc func pressedUserImage(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) { ... }
```

Comment: I guess I confused it with UIButtons!

Comment: "you should also flag the function as Objective-C if your class is not an Objective-C class". Why? Where is objective-c coming anywhere into the question?

Comment: Selectors are an Objective-C construct. In order for the runtime to be able to reach a function using a selector it must use Objective-C style dispatching.

Comment: Note that for selectors on buttons and gesture recognizers this is rarely an issue because the usual target is a UIViewController, which is an Objective-C class.